# How to directly set a value to an UI Image's alpha channel(not the percentage of rendering)

Tags: unity

When you write the code bellow, it renders a percentage of an image's predefined alpha value (which you define in unity's inspector - for example if you define the alpha value of an image to 100, the code bellow actually makes it 25, when the scene is being rendered)

```
_image.GetComponent<CanvasRenderer>.SetAlpha(.25f);
```

How can i rewrite the code above, to directly set an alpha value? Thanks.

Comment: It's not a percentage, its just *multiplied* (100 x .25 is 25). It confirms this in [the API](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/CanvasRenderer.SetAlpha.html). *"CanvasRenderer.SetAlpha(): Set the alpha of the renderer. Will be multiplied with the UIVertex alpha and the Canvas alpha."*

Comment: @Gnemlock thanks for better detail, but when you multiply a number to '0.xx', you receive the xx percentage of the number. That's why i explained my issue using "percentage". Plus that's not my issue.

Comment: To clarify, it kind of is. From what you describe, *you want to change the alpha on an image*. You should apply said changes to the *image*. Not the *canvas renderer*.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your wanting to edit the alpha of an `Image`, but your attempting to change the alpha on the `CanvasRenderer`. This value only *multiplies* the alpha value of the image, resulting in the behaviour you describe.

---

Instead, you should edit the alpha attached to the `Image`. This is fairly simple to do, but you need to remember that you are using `UnityEngine.UI.Image`. You will need to include the `using UnityEngine.UI` namespace, or write the complete address.

From there, it is as simple as retrieving the `Color` and changing the `a` value. Note that you actually have to retrieve the `Color`, as shown in the code below, as you can not directly change `Color.a` from another script.

```
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.UI;
using UnityEditor;

public class MockTransition : MonoBehaviour 
{
    public Image image;
    public float newAlpha;

    public void ChangeAlpha()
    {
        Color newColor = image.color;
        newColor.a = newAlpha;
        image.color = newColor;
    }
}
```

---

You can see this method in action, below. For testing purposes, I attached the method to the editor, and used it to submit values of `0` and `255`. While the `Image` does not actually have an *image* attached to it, you can still clearly see the change in the `Color` value.

[image: Calling the ChangeAlpha() script on a black background image has an immediate effect.]

Comment: @MrChips, to speculate, I'm betting you spent some time scratching your head and wondering why you couldnt directly access the `Image` in the first place. `UnityEngine.UI` got me for a bit, too, when it was first released. Make sure, in these situations, that you look over the available namespaces under `UnityEngine`. Unity have a habit of creating new namespaces for ease of management.

Comment: well actually I'd added the UnityEngine.UI for an another set of codes (specifically for what I've written in my question), which to be honest got me to a couple of times! The problem is that I'm new to unity, and what i really was looking for was the content inside your ChangeAlpha method. Thanks again for that.

Comment: Please ignore my misspells, cant edit them!